# add drop shadow on a table view header

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tableview

I have this following header for my table view header section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let view = UIView()

    view.backgroundColor = .white



    // add a button
    let button = UIButton(type : .system)
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0 , width: 20 , height: 20 )

    if(collapsed[section])
    { button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)}
    else
    { button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)}

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadTable), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.tag = section
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()



    // add an Image
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sup1"))
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 150 , y: 5 , width: 100 , height: 100)
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(image)


    // add a label
    let lblNew = UILabel()
    lblNew.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100 , width: 100, height: 30)
    lblNew.text = "١٢٣ ر.س"
    lblNew.textColor = UIColor.myDarkGreen
    lblNew.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(lblNew)



   // view.dropShadow()

    return view

}
```

Now I want to add drop shadow effect on the section header to look like this

[image: The desire output]

I have tried some solutions here but it works on simple view that is not used as a viewForHeaderInSection, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `view`'s `layer`'s shadow properties:

```
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
view.layer.shadowRadius = 1
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, It seems like the effect can be seen clearly only in the bottom section, I can see only a line between 2 sections.

Comment: @fatimahshams then there has to be a problem somewhere else in your code. check my updated screenshot.

Comment: I just played around the constant in your answer, now it works fine! thank you